# How do I find nth element of a bokeh.core.property.containers.PropertyValueColumnData object in python?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am creating an interactive graph using bokeh/bokeh server and my source data comes from ColumnDataSource. I implemented a tap tool and the selected value can be accessed by "sample_missing_source.selected.indices" that returns index n of the source data. I want to use the selected value to change another graph. However, I am unable to iterate through sample_missing_source.data to attain the data for the nth element.

```
selected = source.selected.indices
print(selected)
[14]

source.data=ColumnDataSource.from_df(df.loc[(df.id == 'test_000') & (df.file == 'test_data.csv')])

print(source.data)
{'completed': array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64),
 'interval': array(['97', '97', '97', '97', '97', '97', '97', '97', '97', '97', '97',
        '97', '97', '97', '97'], dtype=object),
 'missing': array([ 3,  3,  4,  4, 14,  3,  3,  4,  4, 14,  3,  3,  4,  4, 14],
       dtype=int64),
 'month': array(['44', '44', '44', '44', '44', '46', '46', '46', '46', '46', '72',
        '72', '72', '72', '72'], dtype=object),
 'file': array(['lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv',
        'lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv',
        'lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv',
        'lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv',
        'lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv', 'lfq_aggregate.csv'],
       dtype=object),
 'id': array(['2613001', '2613001', '2613001', '2613001', '2613001', '2613001',
        '2613001', '2613001', '2613001', '2613001', '2613001', '2613001',
        '2613001', '2613001', '2613001'], dtype=object),
 'total': array([ 3,  3,  4,  4, 14,  3,  3,  4,  4, 14,  3,  3,  4,  4, 14],
       dtype=int64),
 'value': array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64),
 'variable': array(['lfq_leis_frnd_scr_missing', 'lfq_leis_fam_scr_missing',
        'lfq_duties_home_scr_missing', 'lfq_duties_oth_scr_missing',
        'lfq_missing', 'lfq_leis_frnd_scr_missing',
        'lfq_leis_fam_scr_missing', 'lfq_duties_home_scr_missing',
        'lfq_duties_oth_scr_missing', 'lfq_missing',
        'lfq_leis_frnd_scr_missing', 'lfq_leis_fam_scr_missing',
        'lfq_duties_home_scr_missing', 'lfq_duties_oth_scr_missing',
        'lfq_missing'], dtype=object),
 'index': array([105808, 106679, 107519, 108471, 109505, 110460, 111346, 112207,
        113171, 114204, 174328, 175392, 176428, 177561, 178734])}
```

I am interested in getting the nth element (in this case 14th element) of each array of this object. Any ideas?

Comment: What you mean by "I am unable to iterate"? What have you done so far to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PropertyValueColumnData` inherits the regular `dict` and keeps its semantics, so you can use it as a regular dictionary:

```py
idx = selected[0]
row = {c: v[idx] for c, v in source.data.items()}
```

If you need to, you can convert it to `pandas.Series` by just calling `Series(row)`.